# Avoid compiler warning using wildcard for primitive types in Spock

Tags: testing, groovy, spock

I'm using Spock Framework for testing my Java application. The compiler warns me whenever I try to instrument a `Mock` using a wildcard for a primitive type.

For example (trivial example):

```
service.add(_, _) >> 42
```

Both the above parameters are primitive `int`. The compiler gives me the following warning:

> Warning:(34, 30) 'add' in 'Service' cannot be applied to '(java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object)'

At runtime, the test passed without any problem. However, if I try to specify the type of wildcards, the test fails.

How can I avoid the above warning message?

Comment: Does `service.add(_ as int, _ as int) >> 42` work?

Comment: Nope. As I said, the test fails if I try to specify the type of wildcards.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use type wrappers instead of primitives.

See the project at [github.com/jeffbrown/riccardocardin](https://github.com/jeffbrown/riccardocardin).

[lib/src/test/groovy/riccardocardin/LibraryTest.groovy#L9](https://github.com/jeffbrown/riccardocardin/blob/6a140e72a64efe89f2d6b85dd19f77ef48ff1bdf/lib/src/test/groovy/riccardocardin/LibraryTest.groovy#L9) works.

```
1 * add(_ as Integer, _ as Integer) >>  2112
```

[github.com/spockframework/spock/issues/669](https://github.com/spockframework/spock/issues/669) explains why this is not a bug.

Comment: I too didn't know that primitives weren't valid there. TIL